# How to remove old version of java during silent install?

Tags: command-line, java, silent-install

I want to install Java silently and during this install, I want to uninstall older versions of Java.

Since 8.20 , there is an option to uninstall older version when you run the install (via the GUI).

So I want to know if there is an option for my command line when I want to install it?

Currently, the command line looks like:

```
java.exe /s
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to uninstall older veserion of java :

```
Start /wait msiexec.exe /x {Product code of your older java 64bit} /qn /norestart
```

First we need to find the product code of java older version. For this go to regedit in path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and find your java version.

For my case of Java 8 Update 31 is `26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218031F0` for 32 bit.

For 64 bit only change this number 32 to 64: `2F83218031F0` to `2F86418031F0`.

For more information see full post [here](http://www.get-itsolutions.com/java-silent-install-version-8-and-uninstall-older-version/).

Comment: Adding the detail from the linked post would improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

On later x64 versions, you should use REMOVEOLDERJRES=1

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Per the Java website you can enable this by adding REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1
so it would be **java.exe /s REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1**